# Can I use Excel keybindings in Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, key-binding

LibreOffice Calc has its own set of keybindings, which is different to those in Excel.

Is there a "compatibility mode", or some way to match Excel's keybindings?

I know I can change the bindings one by one, but surely this has been done before for the entire set of keys?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this has been asked before:

Once the keybindings are stored somewhere they can be shared, is my understanding.

1. https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98255
2. https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/where-does-lo-store-keyboards-shortcuts/1516
3. excel shortcuts in progress: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AmDXLkQiFK5OcOrtuGn7iAcqp2Yhc_eNNnlADk-ji-U/edit#gid=0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1139288)